# Read data from sharepoint excel file to Servicenow knowledge article using html editor

Tags: javascript, html, excel, sharepoint, servicenow

I am trying to extract data from an excel file in **sharepoint** and display it into a knowledge article in **servicenow**. The format of data needs to be changed and the data itself needs to be manipulated. So I need to use HTML editor for this purpose which is the only option for manipulating data in knowledge articles. Also, knowledge articles only have option of using an HTML editor to read data. The knowledge article needs to be dynamic i.e. any data updated in excel sheet should be updated in knowledge article when it is reloaded. Does anyone have an insight as to how this task can be approached?

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to actually do any of the data manipulation in the HTML editor... basically if you integrate with Sharepoint, you can have the value of the Article's Body field (which is a HTML field) updated dynamically. You will probably need to do some processing of the content to store it in the right format in ServiceNow. There's plenty of resource son how to integrate with SP online. You might even find some free ones on Share.

Another way to do this would be to activate the External Content for your KB. I suppose it could work but I have not tried that yet. Here's a link to the docs for that to get you started:
https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/orlando-servicenow-platform/page/product/knowledge-management/concept/knowledge-external-content-integration.html